# Query works in PgAdmin but not in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, timeout

I have this query (PostgreSQL): https://gist.github.com/patrickmaciel/74c72cdf1984bdcde804

It's works in PgAdmin, EMS Client, Navicat, Postgres Command Line, whatever.
I test this query in 2 versions of Postgres databases:

- 8.2: 19s
- 9.2: 16ms

But doesn't work in CakePHP with `$this->query($sql);`: *2013-03-11 17:59:48 Error: [FatalErrorException] Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded*.

**Is CakePHP executing/running this query in a different way?**

```
#8 ...........................\app\Controller\Component\CommonCheckComponent.php(64): CommonCheckComponent->validateCheckPromotion(Array, Array, NULL)
#9 ...........................\app\Controller\Component\CommonCheckComponent.php(40): CommonCheckComponent->applyCheckPromotion(Array, Array)
#10 ...........................\app\Controller\Component\CommonTableComponent.php(56): CommonCheckComponent->insertDefaultPromotions(Array)
#11 ...........................\app\Controller\ChecksController.php(42): CommonTableComponent->putTableInCheck(Array, '374')
#12 [internal function]: ChecksController->printCheck('28')
#13 ...........................\lib\Cake\Controller\Controller.php(486): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(ChecksController), Array)
#14 ...........................\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(187): Controller->invokeAction(Object(CakeRequest))
#15 ...........................\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(162): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(ChecksController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#16 ...........................\app\webroot\index.php(109): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#17 {main}
2013-03-11 17:59:48 Error: Fatal Error (1): Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in [...........................\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.ph
p, line 460]
2013-03-11 17:59:48 Error: [FatalErrorException] Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded
Request URL: /patrick/chima-rms/chimarms/checks/printCheck/28
Stack Trace:
#0 ...........................\lib\Cake\Error\ErrorHandler.php(184): ErrorHandler::handleFatalError(1, 'Maximum executi...', 'C:\www\patrick\...', 460)
#1 [internal function]: ErrorHandler::handleError(1, 'Maximum executi...', 'C:\www\patrick\...', 460, Array)
#2 ...........................\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(927): call_user_func('ErrorHandler::h...', 1, 'Maximum executi...', 'C:\www\patrick\...', 460, Array)
#3 ...........................\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(900): App::_checkFatalError()
#4 [internal function]: App::shutdown()
#5 {main}
2013-03-11 17:59:49 Error: Fatal Error (1): Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in [...........................\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\CakeSession.
php, line 616]
2013-03-11 17:59:49 Error: [FatalErrorException] Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded
Request URL: /patrick/chima-rms/chimarms/checks/printCheck/28
Stack Trace:
#0 ...........................\lib\Cake\Error\ErrorHandler.php(184): ErrorHandler::handleFatalError(1, 'Maximum executi...', 'C:\www\patrick\...', 616)
#1 [internal function]: ErrorHandler::handleError(1, 'Maximum executi...', 'C:\www\patrick\...', 616, Array)
#2 ...........................\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(927): call_user_func('ErrorHandler::h...', 1, 'Maximum executi...', 'C:\www\patrick\...', 616, Array)
#3 ...........................\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(900): App::_checkFatalError()
#4 [internal function]: App::shutdown()
#5 {main}
2013-03-11 18:00:11 Error: Fatal Error (1): Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in [...........................\lib\Cake\Utility\Debugger.php, line 47
3]
2013-03-11 18:00:11 Error: [FatalErrorException] Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded
Request URL: /patrick/chima-rms/chimarms/checks/printCheck/28
Stack Trace:
#0 ...........................\lib\Cake\Error\ErrorHandler.php(184): ErrorHandler::handleFatalError(1, 'Maximum executi...', 'C:\www\patrick\...', 473)
#1 [internal function]: ErrorHandler::handleError(1, 'Maximum executi...', 'C:\www\patrick\...', 473, Array)
#2 ...........................\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(927): call_user_func('ErrorHandler::h...', 1, 'Maximum executi...', 'C:\www\patrick\...', 473, Array)
#3 ...........................\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(900): App::_checkFatalError()
#4 [internal function]: App::shutdown()
#5 {main}
```

Why?

---

I'm using:

- CakePHP 2.3.0
- PostgreSQL 9.2
- PHP 5.3.9
- Apache 2.2
- Windows 7 x64

Comment: We can't do much with "doesn't work." Give us an error message. The more detail the better.

Comment: Now I add more details

Comment: how long does the query take in the other environments?

Comment: In Postgres 8.2 = 19s / in 9.2 = 16ms.

Comment: Are you certain it's not a case where you are returning from the database query and the processing of the result in php is taking a long time? I'm not a php programmer, but google tells me that you can change the max_execution_time for the script.

Comment: One option: Install the `auto_explain` module and use it to see the query plan for the problem query. Compare it to the result of `explain`ing the query in PgAdmin-III. Are they different? If so, paste both here. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html

Answer (score 2):

By default the maximum execution time of PHP script is 30s. When you run this SQL, the time to return and process data is greater than 30s. You need to increase the maximum execution time or optimize your query.
Try set_time_limit(0); at the top of your script.